# Dog class DogApp

Tags: java

I need to make two Java classes(Dog, DogApp). The class Dog needs to be able to set and get name, breed, color, weight, height, and length. The class also must have a bark statement at the end with variable name included. I have the class Dog made, but in the DogApp class I'm getting syntax errors on the getName, getBreed, getColor, getWeight, getHeight, and getLength lines. What am I doing wrong?
any help would be greatly appreciated, and I do realize versions of this question exhist but not the same.
Dog class:

```
public class Dog {
    private static Object sc;
    private String name;
    private String breed;
    private String color;
    private double weight;
    private double height;
    private double length;

   public Dog() {
       name = null;
       breed = null;
       color = null;
       weight = 0;
       height = 0;
       length = 0;
   }

 public static Object getSc() {
     return sc;
 }

 public static void setSc(Object sc) {
     Dog.sc = sc;
 }

 public String getName() {
     return name;
 }

 public void setName(String name) {
     this.name = name;
 }

 public String getBreed() {
     return breed;
 }

 public void setBreed(String breed) {
     this.breed = breed;
 }

 public String getColor() {
     return color;
 }

 public void setColor(String color) {
     this.color = color;
 }

 public double getWeight() {
     return weight;
 }

 public void setWeight(double weight) {
     this.weight = weight;
 }

 public double getHeight() {
     return height;
 }

 public void setHeight(double height) {
     this.height = height;
 }

 public double getLength() {
     return length;
 }

 public void setLength(double length) {
     this.length = length;
 }

 public String Bark(String bark) {
     bark = (name + " says woof.");
     return bark;
 }
}

******
DogApp:

 import java.util.Scanner;

public class DogApp {

private static String name;
private static String breed;
private static String color;
private static double weight;
private static double height;
private static double length;
private static String bark;

public static void main(String args[]) {
    // display a welcome message
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String choice = "y";
    while (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
        System.out.print("Enter Dog's information");
        System.out.println();
        Dog dog = new Dog();

        System.out.print("Enter dog's name: ");
        name = sc.nextLine();
        dog.setName(name);

        System.out.print("Enter Dog's breed: ");
        dog.setBreed(breed);
        breed = sc.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Enter Dog's color: ");
        dog.setColor(color);
        color = sc.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Enter Dog's weight: ");
        dog.setWeight(weight);
        weight = sc.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("Enter Dog's height: ");
        dog.setHeight(height);
        height = sc.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("Enter Dog's length: ");
        dog.setLength(length);
        length = sc.nextDouble();

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("name:     " + (name));
        System.out.println("breed:    " + (breed));
        System.out.println("color:    " + (color));
        System.out.println("weight:   " + (weight));
        System.out.println("height:   " + (height));
        System.out.println("length:   " + (length));
        System.out.println(dog.getBark(bark));
        System.out.print("Continue?  y/n: ");
        choice = sc.next();

    }

  }
}
```

Comment: If you're seeing compiler errors, it would be wise to post the error messages here and indicate which lines cause them.

Comment: By the way, what is the purpose of that static Object sc field? It looks unnecessary and possibly confusing.

Comment: warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.7
C:\Users\No Trespassing\Desktop\murach\java\netbeans\book_apps\ch07_LineItem\src\bakerg4\DogApp.java:14: error: method getName in class Dog cannot be applied to given types;
            String name = Dog.getName(
  required: no arguments
  found: String

Comment: The auto add code function of netbeans generated the Object sc. I'm not sure why.

Comment: This information should be part of your original question above as an edit as it is key information. You're calling `getName()` and similar getXXX() methods, methods that are not supposed to take parameters, and you're passing in a String parameter. The compiler is complaining that what you're doing is not legal, and the compiler is of course correct. Solution: don't do this.

Answer (score 2):

You're calling the methods statically. Static methods should be reserved for methods that take all the information they need in the method signature. You have also swapped your getter and setter methods.

Try creating an object of type dog, and assigning the data to it:

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    Dog currentDog = new Dog();

    String name = sc.next();
    currentDog.setName(name);
    String breed = sc.next();
    currentDog.setBreed(breed);
    String color = sc.next();
    currentDog.setColor(color);
    double weight = sc.nextDouble();
    currentDog.setWeight(weight);
    double height = sc.nextDouble();
    currentDog.setHeight(height);
    double length = sc.nextDouble();
    currentDog.setLength(length);
```

Then to retrieve your data:

```
    String name = currentDog.getName();
    String breed = currentDog.getBreed();
    String color = currentDog.getColor();
    double weight = currentDog.getWeight();
    double height = currentDog.getHeight();
    double length = currentDog.getLength();
```

For the methods... 
[Understanding Class Members](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

Another resource you should look into is [Scanner API Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)
on how to use the scanner object.

Comment: I edited the DogApp and resubmitted the code using the edit function. Now the program will cycle through and display the information and prompt the user to continue. After a "y" is entered the program drops the name and breed input on the same line. Any ideas? Thank you for the help I've received. Instead of just talking badly about a noob's bad code, you decided to offer help. I greatly appreciate your assistance.